# android app screen compatibility using HTML5 development

Tags: android, html, android-layout

I'm creating a cross-platform application using HTML5(for BlackBerry z10, Android, and iOS). I just want to ask how to apply the compatibility of the to all Android smartphones(2.3 and up maybe and also for iOS) since I use HMTL5, JS, and CSS3? By the way I will be using Twitter Bootstrap.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Every model of phone supports `WebView`. If you are using a pure HTML5 app, there will be no compatibility problems.